# How to make a UIView focusable using the focus engine on Apple TV

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv, focus-engine

Is it possible to make a `UIView` focusable? Or should I just use a custom `UIButton` for all possible views?

I tried to override `canBecomeFocused` but nothing happened.

Comment: yes, any UIView is focusable using canBecomeFocused.  However, you also need to override the didUpdateFocusInContext method to display the focus.

Comment: you MUST also add **isUserInteractionEnabled = true**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So the problem was that I didn't notice that my cell got focus. To wrap this up, you need to implement

1) override canBecomeFocused

2) override "didUpdateFocusInContext:withAnimationCoordinator:" method to be able to highlight the cell as focused

**Swift 2.3:**

```
override func canBecomeFocused() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {

    if context.nextFocusedView == self {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
            self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2).CGColor
        }, completion: nil)
    } else if context.previouslyFocusedView == self {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
            self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
override var canBecomeFocused: Bool {
    return true
}

override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if context.nextFocusedView == self {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
            self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
        }, completion: nil)

    } else if context.previouslyFocusedView == self {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
            self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: must also have isUserInteractionEnabled = true

Answer (score 3):

It seems that things had changed and now the correct way to make a view focusable is this:

`override var canBecomeFocused : Bool {
        return true
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 version of Pavel's code:

```
override var canBecomeFocused: Bool {
    return true
}

override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {

    if context.nextFocusedView == self {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
            self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
        }, completion: nil)

    } else if context.previouslyFocusedView == self {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
            self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: isUserInteractionEnabled = true