# selectedViewcontroller not working for tabbarcontroller in tvOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tvos, focus-engine

I have a `rootviewcontroller` which is extending `UITabBarController`. It has several children `viewcontrollers`.

All I want is to programmatically select the 2nd/3rd/.. `viewcontroller` from the first one. I've used

```
`.selectedViewController`, `.selectedIndex`, `.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem = ...`
```

and all the variations on this theme. I notice the following when using

```
`tabBarController.selectedViewController = tabBarController.viewControllers?[1]`
```

The `tabBarController` displays the 2nd `viewcontroller` for a second but goes back to the 1st `viewcontroller`. I have a hunch this is the focus engine but I'm lost at this point.

Comment: Where u do all these codes?

Answer (score 4):

Not completely sure if it's related but I had a tvOS app where I had several UIViewControllers in a UITabBarController and I stopped being able to select them in the tab bar and have the tab bar go away once I upgraded to tvOS 10.

Turns out the issue is that those screens did not have any focusable elements on them (buttons, etc.) so I had to make subclass objects for some of the views and make the `canBecomeFocused` property return "true".

see: [How to make a UIView focusable using the focus engine on Apple TV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071053/how-to-make-a-uiview-focusable-using-the-focus-engine-on-apple-tv)

You have to implement a second thing to make them appear focused but if you don't actually want that you can skip it.

Answer (score 0):

I was setting an UITabBarItem for each controller.